# Set a different length for each animation

Tags: animation, timeline

I have a blender model and I have been making a few simple animations with it. Prior to today I could select the animation in the Dope Sheet and go to Timeline, set the Start/End frames and leave it at that. I could then do the same for another animation and both would have their own length.

It seems I touched something I wasn't supposed to because now when I set the Start and End frames for one of the animations it changes it for all of the other ones.

Any idea how I could set a particular number of frames for each one of my animations ?

Answer (score 0):

It's looks like you have same animation data for different objects. So try this: Select the objects and press <kbd>U</kbd> -> **Animation data** to create a copy of it for all your objects